# Convert a String from LowerTo Upper (vice-versa) without using type casting or built-in functions in Java

Tags: java

How can we convert a String from lower to upper (Vice-versa ) in Java 
without using any built-in function or using any type casting ?

Comment: A rather large loop through your String...`if(str.charAt(i) == 'a'...)` , or perhaps view the source code of the `String` class and find the method that does this already...or does this count as using the inbuilt `charAt` method? Or have a map of all characters lower case and upper case and have the values as the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASCII values to change cases. in your case converting lower case alphabets to upper case loweer case **a** has ASCII value **97** and **z** has **122** and if these number is exactly subtracted by **32** then it will be equal to ASCII value of its uppercase letter like **97-32=65** is ASCII value of **A**. Hope this helps.

```
public class toUpperCase{
        public static void main(String[] args){

            toUpperCase(args[0]);
        }

        //for lower to upper case
        public static void toUpperCase(String a){

            for (int i = 0; i< a.length(); i++){

                char aChar = a.charAt(i);
                if (97 <= aChar && aChar<=122){
                    aChar = (char)( (aChar - 32) ); 
                }

                System.out.print(aChar);
            }
         }
        //for upper to lower case   
        public static void toUpperCase(String a){

            for (int i = 0; i< a.length(); i++){

                char aChar = a.charAt(i);
                if (65 <= aChar && aChar<= 97){
                    aChar = (char)( (aChar + 32) ); 
                }

                System.out.print(aChar);
            }
         }            
    }
```

But, again it needs typecasting.
for ASCII values check [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Check your code, it does not works! `aChar` goes nowhere

Comment: Thanks for letting me know we should print aChar

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String toUpperCase(String str) {
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] >= 'a' && arr[i] <= 'z')
            arr[i] -= 'a' - 'A';

    return new String(arr);
}

public static String toLowerCase(String str) {
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] >= 'A' && arr[i] <= 'Z')
            arr[i] += 'a' - 'A';

    return new String(arr);
}
```